# How to use date as a primary key in Realm database?

Tags: android, date, search, realm, primary-key

I am working in Realm database. I know how to use id as a primary key. But I want to know how to use date as a primary key so that if I search any date it should be viewed on the screen. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: from when you cant search on columns which are not pk ... same with showing in UI

Comment: I dint get your answer. Can you please tell me clearly

Comment: He says, your field does **not** have to be a primary key in order to query from it. Just add `@Index`.

Answer (score 1):

Using date as primary key usually is not a good idea. As you can face situation where you need 2 object have same date but primary key can't be same for 2 objects.

Any way making date as a primary key is easy:

```
public class SomeModel extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long date;
    ...
    public long getDate(){return date;}
    public void setDate(long date) {this.date = date;}
}
```

Example how to create object:

```
SomeModel rv = realm.createObject(SomeModel.class, new Date().getTime());
```